# Where is the C precompiler for Oracle10g located?

Tags: oracle10g, precompiler

I am looking for a newer version of the Pro*C/C++ to upgrade my procui.exe 9.0.1.1.1. 
I downloaded the 10g client disk and when install I have the following options:

```
 instant client     
 administrator
 runtime
 custom
```

I dont seem to able to find the actual program other than just getting some common files. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a custom install, you should eventually get to a screen titled "Available Product Components". Select the Oracle Programmer option, along with any other items you like. That should install the precompilers for you.

Comment: I did and it created amongst other thing c:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\precomp with 5 subfolders all support files but not the program itself.

Comment: Hmmm, I just did it and it installed proc.exe in the client_1\bin directory. I don't think procui.exe exists any more. You have to use the command line interface.

Answer (score 3):

Procui.exe was discontinued after 9i.  You can see a good deal of chatter about that change in the forums.  It is recommended to call proc.exe via the command line.

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=217034